# HTTParty parsed_response returns a String instead of Hash

Tags: ruby, httparty

HTTParty's `parsed_response` method returns a Hash if you get a response code 200 but otherwise it will return a String regardless if the webserver returns a XML response.

```
HTTParty.get(post_url).parsed_response.class # Depends on response code
```

Amazon will provide XML (explaining what went wrong) even on a 403.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 15):

HTTParty parses its `#parsed_response` based on what the HTTP response's `Content-Type` header is. Verify what the value is for that HTTP header. In your case, you'd want it to be `application/xml`.

Comment: This got me with webmock/httparty. Needed application/json content type

Comment: @Andrew So how to get it right with Webmock? I've got no idea how to get the parsed JSON.

Comment: @Nowaker, I'm not sure if you sorted this out, but webmock incorrectly gives you the _exact_ code you you should stub with. It neglects, however, to include the response headers that httparty relies on to decide how to parse. Add those and it works fine.

Comment: I too am getting a `String` returned instead of `JSON` from `Instagram`.  `content-type` shows it's "text/html".  [example](https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=prawncocktail)

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone is still encountering this issue today, `get` can take a format parameter, which can help you ensure your `HTTParty::Response` object is a Hash:

```
url = HTTParty.get('http://domain.com', format: :json) # class is a Hash
```

Comment: this fixed it for me, when the content type header did not.